# Maintain the aspect ratio of an image with CSS for small screens

Tags: html, css, performance, image-scaling, lighthouse

I'm trying to fix the Lighthouse warning "Image elements do not have explicit width and height" to reduce layout shifts and improve CLS. The problem is that when I created my pages on a WP site I used the bootstrap grid and didn't add those attributes to images, so they were resizing just fine on all screens.
Now if I add width and height attribites the image is not scaled correctly on mobile devices, the initial aspect ratio is not respected.
My biggest concern is that the images are very different, and the aspect ratio is very different, too.
That's the only working solution I found, yet I don't think it's really elegant, guess there should be something more... simple ?

So here is the piece of code that goes into css :

```
[style*="--aspect-ratio"]>:first-child {
    width: 100%
}

[style*="--aspect-ratio"]>img {
    height: auto
}

@supports (--custom:property) {
    [style*="--aspect-ratio"] {
        position: relative
    }

    [style*="--aspect-ratio"]::before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: calc(100% / (var(--aspect-ratio)))
    }

    [style*="--aspect-ratio"]>:first-child {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%
    }
}
```

And I have to manually add a parent div to each image, indicating the width/height ratio :

```
<div style="--aspect-ratio:804/476">
        <img src="/app/uploads/2020/06/picture.png" alt="alt text" width="804" height="476" />
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Not entirely sure what the issue is that is causing you to do this workaround? Are you saying that you have a different aspect ratio on small screens (an entirely different image) than on large screens? If you are using the same image and just scaling it then you have no need for all of the wrapping div stuff, simply add `width` and `height` attributes to each image (which can be done server side) and make sure in your CSS the image has `width: 100%` to fill it's parent container. You may need to explain better / add some more detail if that isn't the issue you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

So I was playing around with it and I found out that if you have width and height attributes the image is properly resized when you have

```
img {
max-width: 100%
height: auto
}
```

Hope it can help someone else too!